# Input field mendatory LWC

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I need help to put the input fiel required. When a user click on Search, if the search field is empty, an error message should show in red.

````
```<template>

<div class="slds-grid">
    <div class="slds-col">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter id here" required="" value={inputId} onchange={onchangeIdhandler}    class="slds-input" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col  slds-p-horizontal_large">
        <button class="bg slds-button slds-align_absolute-center"  onclick={handleSearch}>Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
````

```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [error variant](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input/?variant=base#Error) from the SLDS library as a start point to implement your own input with an error message.

For example, in your html you could do something like the following:

```html
<template>
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <div class="slds-col">
            <div class={inputCss}>
                <label class="slds-form-element__label"> Input Label </label>
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter id here" required="" value={inputId} onchange={onchangeIdhandler} class="slds-input" />
                </div>
                <template if:true={error}>
                    <div class="slds-form-element__help">{error}</div>
                </template>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-p-horizontal_large">
            <button class="bg slds-button slds-align_absolute-center" onclick={handleSearch}>Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And in the javascript controller, you would add properties to show the error:

```js
// ... other imports
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class InputError extends LightningElement {
    // ... other properties
    error = "";

    get inputCss() {
        let classes = "slds-form-element";

        if (this.error) {
            classes.push("slds-has-error");
        }

        return classes.join(" ");
    }

    // ... other methods
}
```

Comment: the error should show in the field